# MongoDB return only created document instand of refetching whole collection

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, redux-toolkit

Is there any way to do this? I dont know if i asked good question, but here is what i mean.

Let's say i have todo app and  while i create new todo i would like to update my list with this todo without refetching whole colletion.
Like in firebase realtime database.

Im using react and redux-tookit.

Fetch data at 1st render then i trigger fetch again after new todo being saved to monogdb.

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getTodos());
  }, [dispatch]);

const handleAddTodo = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const todo = {
      title: todoValue,
    };
    dispatch(addTodo(todo))
      dispatch(getTodos())
      setTodoValue("");
    });
  };
```

Comment: You might want to look into optimistic rendering. Basically you just assume that the create is going to work and add the data to your client state.

Comment: Otherwise, since dispatch is asynchronous, you would have to add a dispatch to the getTodos action on the redux side.

Comment: export const getTodos = createAsyncThunk("todos/getTodos", async () => {
  const response = await axios.get(API);
  return response.data;
}); but still after new todo is saved to db i need to call this fucntion

Comment: I think this is what you need https://stackoverflow.com/a/63523157/5708566