# Dispatching actions of one slice inside other slices in Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm useing Redux ToolKit in my project. My question is how can I dispatch action from one slice inside another one. What is the best practice here?
I have a separate slice for notification. It has open:boolean property and some other ones like status, message etc. I have put Notification component in the bottom of Layout component so that Notification is on every page. If i set state.notification.open to true Notification will pop up. To do that I need to dispatch action of notificationSlice.
I need notification to pop up after some axios requests for example. Now I dispatch that action inside createAsyncThunk callback. But is it good way to do that? Moreover sometimes I would like to do that inside reducers funcitons and extraReducers functions. But it looks like I can't since I don't have dispatch function there (May be I'm wrong).
So the idea is to be able to change Notification state (inside notificationSlice) from other slices after some logic is done

```
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setAuth: (state, action: PayloadAction<IUser>) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
    CAN I CHANGE OTHER SLICE STATE FROME HERE ??
    },
  },
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
      .addCase(login.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = true;
        console.log('login.pending', action);
      })
      .addCase(login.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
    CAN I CHANGE OTHER SLICE STATE FROME HERE ??
        console.log('login.fulfilled', action);
      })
      .addCase(login.rejected, (state, action) => {
        console.log('login.rejected', action);
      });
  },
});
```

Comment: look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63516716/redux-toolkit-is-it-possible-to-dispatch-other-actions-from-the-same-slice-in-o)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also edited my question and marked two places. Can I do it from there? Inside reducers and extraReducers